# How to use DJI OSDK to make M100 fly to a desired GPS Location?

Tags: dji-sdk

I am very new to DJI OSDK. I am currently working on a project, where I need to give the GPS coordinates of a certain location to my M100 and it will fly to that location.

I am currently following the DJI OSDK documentation for Ubntu Linux. I tried using the Waypoints Mission.

In the 'Waypoints' mission, if I set the variable 'wayptPolygonSides' to 1, and then set the desired the GPS coordinates in the iterative algorithm for generating the waypoint, I get this:

```
STATUS/1 @ getErrorCodeMessage, L656: runWaypointMission
STATUS/1 @ getCMDSetMissionMSG, L883: MISSION_OBTAIN_CONTROL_REQUIRED

STATUS/1 @ printInfo, L204: Mission Manager status:

STATUS/1 @ printInfo, L205: There are 1 waypt missions and 0 hotpoint missions
Initializing Waypoint Mission..
Waypoint created at (LLA): 0.534897 -1.680698 10.000000
Creating Waypoints..
Waypoint created at (LLA): 0.534897 -1.680698 10.000000

STATUS/1 @ getErrorCodeMessage, L656: uploadWaypoints
STATUS/1 @ getCMDSetMissionMSG, L883: WAYPOINT_MISSION_DATA_NOT_ENOUGH
Waypoint created at (LLA): 0.534900 -1.681000 15.000000

STATUS/1 @ getErrorCodeMessage, L656: uploadWaypoints
STATUS/1 @ getCMDSetMissionMSG, L883: WAYPOINT_MISSION_DATA_NOT_ENOUGH
Waypoint created at (LLA): 0.534897 -1.680698 10.000000

STATUS/1 @ getErrorCodeMessage, L656: uploadWaypoints
STATUS/1 @ getCMDSetMissionMSG, L883: WAYPOINT_MISSION_DATA_NOT_ENOUGH
Uploading Waypoints..

STATUS/1 @ getErrorCodeMessage, L656: runWaypointMission
STATUS/1 @ getCMDSetMissionMSG, L883: MISSION_OBTAIN_CONTROL_REQUIRED
```

Comment: Based on my test, you need at least 3 waypoint for navigation by mission.

Comment: So, is there any other way to give GPS location to the M100? Any suggestions?

Comment: you have to use the /dji_sdk/flight_control_setpoint_genric topic to control it. other method im not aware of

Answer (score 0):

The comment about a minimum number of waypoints isn't correct, far as I know the min wp required = 2. Your problem is evident by this log statement:

```
STATUS/1 @ getCMDSetMissionMSG, L883: MISSION_OBTAIN_CONTROL_REQUIRED
```

If you're following the sample in the DJI OSDK, you'll see in the main.cpp file for mission sample under the linux platform, line 54 of version 3.9.0 requests referenced control:

```
vehicle->obtainCtrlAuthority(functionTimeout);
```

I imagine you're missing this line, or not ensuring it runs correctly.

Additionally, ensure you have the correct control mode selected on the flight controller/Matrice in the DJI Assistant app. See [this](https://developer.dji.com/onboard-sdk/documentation/guides/component-guide-control-authority.html) page for more information on control modes.